# Шарашкина контора — почему шарашкина?

Tags: фразеология

Когда-то мне попадалось разъяснение этого выражения, но сейчас не могу вспомнить его. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему контора — шарашкина? И, кстати, интересно, что в советские времена так называли закрытые институты, а сейчас — учреждения, не вызывающие доверия, липовые.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из "Грамоты.ру":

Шарашкина контора (прост. пренебр.) - несолидное, не вызывающее доверия учреждение, предприятие, организация. Притяжательное прилагательное шарашкина объясняется диалектным шарань "шваль, голытьба, жулье". Шарашкина контора буквально - "учреждение, организация жуликов, обманщиков". Из оборота, в свою очередь, образовано слово шарага "подозрительное место или группа людей".